# Multi position toggle or movable progress bar with html5

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, web-frontend

I'm clueless about web front end, however I am in need to create an html form with input field that would allow 0-10 score to be assigned as an element value. Is there a way to do it with some sort of drawable progress bar or multi position toggle switch?

Answer (score 1):

Use input type=“range”:

```
<input type=“range” min=“0” max=“10”/>
```

Getting value:

```
var value = document.getElementsByTagName(“input”)[0].value
```